# display Graph in javafx , nodes out of stage

Tags: javafx

i m implementing some search algorithms for Graphs , but i need first to set my Gui to display all nodes and edges of the graph , 
tried many Layouts from javafx , but with big graphs i get always some nodes , edges  out of the stage .

which will be the best layout to use to scale and get all Nodes ?

Comment: Best would probably be a ScrollPane.

Comment: thank you , but i need the graph to be automatically scaled to the size of the  shape ,